# Create a range based on the values of two non-adjacent cells in Excel

Tags: excel, cells, vba

This is the example:
On Sheet 3

```
   A   B   C
1  A
2  13
3  190
```

These numbers are generated based on data from different Sheets. How could I create a formula on sheet3 that uses a range based on these numbers.
Something like: c= SUM Sheet1!(A1&A2:A1&A3) to sum the range A13 to A190 that is on sheet 1.
The reason I want to do this is because the number stored in A3 is dynamically generated.
Please, help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
=sum(indirect(a1&a2&":"&a1&a3))
```

INDEX would be better but A1 should contain 1, not A. Example,

```
=sum(index(A:Z, a2, code(upper(a1))-64):index(A:Z, a3, code(upper(a1))-64))
```

Comment: This works well to make the calculations using data from the same sheet, but how do I include the reference to the data on another sheet from the current one to make those calculations?

Comment: Say, from sheet 3 I want to make calculations using range cell A13 to A190 that is on sheet 1

Comment: You will have to use INDIRECT unless you know the wortksheet beforehand. e.g. `=sum(indirect("'"&b1&"'!"&a1&a2&":"&a1&a3))` where B1 has Sheet3.

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps you should double check the name of the worksheet.

Comment: I have double checked the spelling and reference and still the error. When I click inside the formula bar, all cell references change the colors except the Sheet3 reference. Can that be a hint?

Comment: What do you get if you use just `="'"&b1&"'!"&a1&a2&":"&a1&a3` in a cell on sheet1? Copy and paste it back here.

Comment: I would not get the correct result. The references I have on sheet3 are different to the information I have on Sheet1.

Comment: Can I share the file with you or post it for other people to give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The way to solve the problem is to add a reference to the name of the other workbook on the same page. Jeeped solution worked great, but I needed more info in the formula.
I changed my data like this:

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>SHEET1</th> 
    <th>SHEET1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COLUMN</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FIRST CELL</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>190</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LAST CELL</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, the formula ended up like this:

=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!"&B3&B4&":"&B3&B5))

Where B2 was the reference to the cell with the sheet name from which the data was retrieved.

Thank you Jeeped for your help. You were great and I admire your professionalism and speed to point me on the right path.